# Date with text to file

Tags: bash

I'm trying to pipe text into a file:

```
'date +"%H:%M" development' > log
```

Example: 12:12 development

But this actually pipes `date +"%H:%M" development` and not `12:12 development`

Comment: What is the full command you're running? `'date + "%H:%M" development' > log` results in `'date + "%H:%M" development: command not found'` for me. Are you running from the command line or via a bash script file?

Comment: Are you using echo or something beforehand? the `date` command will not output the word development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish the desired output.

The wrong way - the system parses the line, and feeds 'development' as an argument for 'date'. Since the 'date' application does not have such an argument, it throws a helpful error.

```
$ date +"%H:%M" development
date: extra operand ‘development’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
```

Solution #1: Use date formatting

```
$ date +"%H:%M development"
07:10 development
```

Solution #2: Use [Command Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_04)

```
$ echo $(date +"%H:%M") development
07:10 development
```

Comment: Writing answers at the same time, +1 for being speedy and including all relevant info.

Comment: Solution 2 was perfect

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're using `echo` or `printf` or some other command to redirect the output to the log file, otherwise you would get an error message like:

```
bash: date +"%H:%M" development: command not found
```

If this is the case, you'd want to use command substitution to get the output of the `date` command, and also avoid using strong quoting, `' '`, around your string. The following will work:

```
echo "$(date +'%H:%M development')" > log
```

or

```
echo "$(date +'%H:%M) development" > log
```

If you're just using `date` without `echo` etc, then include the string 'development' within the date formatting string, the formatting string can be quoted with either `'` or `"`, as it isn't expanded by bash, but by the `date` command:

```
date +"%H:%M development" > log
```

or

```
date +'%H:%M development' > log
```